# Shell Script for automate SSH logins

Tags: linux, bash

I have created a shell script for login my servers:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Please hostname ..."
while :
do
  read INPUT_STRING
  case $INPUT_STRING in
    host1)
        `bash |sshpass -p 'qwerty123' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.1.4`
         ;;
    host2)
        `sshpass -p 'qwerty123' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.1.8`
         ;;
    *)
        echo "Sorry, I don't understand"
        break;
        ;;
  esac
done
echo 
echo "Bye"
```

But I can´t login to the server. I think the issue may be changing the shell on the scrip while accessing the server.
Please help.

Comment: What errors are you seing?  Also, consider using keys and `~/.ssh/config`.  Your current solution puts passwords available so any user can read them.  Also, bash has no output. It's a shell.  The servers account must be set up to use that shell if that's what you want.  `|` just redirects stdout to the next process following.

Comment: `bash` has output like any other process; most commonly, its output is the file associated with your terminal.

Comment: This is not a smart idea. Instead, consider running an `ssh-agent` and adding your keys via `ssh-add` at shell init.

Answer (score 0):

The back tics are causing your program to fail.  Remove the backticks and also the bash |  and you may have a chance.  All of the comments I've read are correct, though.  You should consider using  a public / private key pair.  You could make your logins to the hosts easier with ~/.ssh/config.

Try this code for now:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Please hostname ..."
while :
do
  read INPUT_STRING
  case $INPUT_STRING in
    host1)
        sshpass -p 'qwerty123' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.1.4
         ;;
    host2)
        sshpass -p 'qwerty123' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.1.8
         ;;
    *)
        echo "Sorry, I don't understand"
        break;
        ;;
  esac
done
echo 
echo "Bye"
```

Here's a one liner that pretty much does the same thing:

```
select INPUT_STRING in host1 host2; do ssh $INPUT_STRING; done
```

However, you'll need to create a ~/.ssh/config file so that host1 and host2 are mapped to IP addresses:

```
Host host1
  HostName 192.168.1.4
  User root
  StrictHostKeyChecking no

Host host2
  HostName 192.168.1.8
  User root
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Also, to avoid the sshpass, you can use commands such as ssh-keygen and ssh-copy-id.  Plenty has been written about ssh-keygen and ssh-copy-id so I won't go into it here (the keywords should be enough to get you far).